# LDAP authentication on server

Tags: c#, ldap, directoryservices, directoryentry

I need to authenticate LDAP user in c# with input username and password.

```
DirectoryEntry entry =
new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + ServerName + "/OU=managed users,OU=KK”, + LDAPDomain, AdminUsername, Adminpassword);

DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
search.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
search.Filter = "(|(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(name=" + inputUsername + ")))";
search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn");
var searchresult = search.FindAll();
```

And here I get the required record (could see the details)
However when I try to authenticate it using below code, it always said authentication failure

```
if (searchresult != null)
{
    foreach (SearchResult sr in searchresult)
    {
        DirectoryEntry myuser = sr.GetDirectoryEntry();
        myuser.Password = inputPassword;
        try
        {
            object nativeObject = myuser.NativeObject;
            if (nativeObject != null)
                isValid = true;
        }
        catch(excecption ex)
        {
            isValid = false;
            //Error message 
        }

    }
}
```

It always result in catch block with error message

> Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password. failure: unknown user name or bad password.

I'm sure that the given password is correct.

Please suggest.

As suggest by Saad, 
I changed by code

```
public static bool IsAuthenticated() 
{
    var isValid = false;
    string adServer = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Server"];
    string adDomain = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Domain"];
    string adminUsername = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AdminUsername"];
    string adminpassword = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"];
    string username = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Username"];
    string selection = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Selection"];
    string[] dc = adDomain.Split('.');
    string dcAdDomain = string.Empty;

    foreach (string item in dc)
    {
        if (dc[dc.Length - 1].Equals(item))
            dcAdDomain = dcAdDomain + "DC=" + item;
        else
            dcAdDomain = dcAdDomain + "DC=" + item + ",";
    }

    string domainAndUsername = dcAdDomain + @"\" + adminUsername;

    DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + adServer, domainAndUsername, adminpassword);

    try
    {                
        //Bind to the native AdsObject to force authentication.
        object obj = entry.NativeObject;             
        DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(entry);

        search.Filter = "(SAMAccountName=" + username + ")";
        search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn");
        SearchResult result = search.FindOne();
        Console.WriteLine("And here is the result = " + result);
        if (null == result)
        {
            isValid = false;
        }

        //Update the new path to the user in the directory.
        var _path1 = result.Path;
        var _filterAttribute = (string)result.Properties["cn"][0];
        Console.WriteLine("And here is the _path1 = " + _path1);
        Console.WriteLine("And here is the _filterAttribute = " + _filterAttribute);
        isValid = true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex1)
    {// your catch here
        Console.WriteLine("Exception occurred " + ex1.Message + ex1.StackTrace);
    }
    return isValid;
}
```

Still it is giving error

```
Exception occurred Logon failure: unknown user name or bad passwor
d.
   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean throwIfFail)
   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind()
   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.get_NativeObject()
   at Portal.LdapTest.Program.IsAuthenticated()
```

I think I am confused with which parameter to give where.
I have 
LDAP server address something like 123.123.12.123
Domain Name like abc.com
**Admin username and password**  and 
**Username and password** which is needs be authenticated. (which is in OU=new users,OU=KK )

I am creating directory entry using servername, domain, admin username and password

How do I validate the username with given password?

Comment: to me its hard to tell,  but im guessing most probably the search filter, have you tried browsing the LDAP Server via some app and making sure that you are looking in the right place?

Comment: I can see the record and its properties in debugging info like                 DirectoryEntry myuser = sr.GetDirectoryEntry(); Console.WriteLine("\r\n\r\nfound userName    : " + myuser.Name); Console.WriteLine("\r\n department  : " + (string)myuser.Properties["department"].Value ?? "<Undefined>");    So I think I have got correct record.

Comment: Is it necessary to provide admin username and password for DirectoryEntry ?
If we pass the current user credentials, will that be sufficient to validate the user against Active Directory
{
     DirectoryEntry entry = new 
     DirectoryEntry("LDAP://****.net/DC=***,DC=net", username, 
     password, AuthenticationTypes.Secure);
                object nativeObject = entry.NativeObject;
                authenticated = true;
}

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me,try it and let me know (modify the filters and properties to suit your needs):

```
        public bool IsAuthenticated(string domain, string username, string pwd){
        string domainAndUsername = domain + @"\" + username;
        DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(_path, domainAndUsername, pwd);

        try
        {

                //Bind to the native AdsObject to force authentication.
                object obj = entry.NativeObject;

                DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(entry);

                search.Filter = "(SAMAccountName=" + username + ")";
                search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn");
                SearchResult result = search.FindOne();

                if (null == result)
                {
                    return false;
                }

                //Update the new path to the user in the directory.
                _path = result.Path;
                _filterAttribute = (string)result.Properties["cn"][0];

        }
        catch(Exception e){// your catch here

        }
}
```

Comment: Hi Saad, I have changed my code as per your's. Still it is giving the same error. FYI, i have admin username and password, to get through LDAP server and the username n pwd which is to authenticated. I hope I have given parameter in correct place.

Comment: well when i had a similiar problem,i went on tinkering about with an AD Browser to figure out what went wrong, i hope you've already found a solution anyways.

Answer (score 0):

```
public bool AuthenticateUser(string EmailAddress, string password,out string msg)
{
    msg = string.Empty;

    if (password == null || password == string.Empty || EmailAddress == null || EmailAddress == string.Empty)
    {
        msg = "Email and/or password can't be empty!";
        return false;
    }

    try
    {
        ADUserInfo userInfo = GetUserAttributes(EmailAddress);

        if (userInfo == null)
        {
            msg = "Error: Couldn't fetch user information!";
            return false;
        }
        DirectoryEntry directoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry(LocalGCUri, userInfo.Upn, password);
        directoryEntry.AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.None;
        string localFilter = string.Format(ADSearchFilter, EmailAddress);


        DirectorySearcher localSearcher = new DirectorySearcher(directoryEntry);
        localSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mail");
        localSearcher.Filter = localFilter;

        SearchResult result = localSearcher.FindOne();


        if (result != null)
        {
            msg = "You have logged in successfully!";
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            msg = "Login failed, please try again.";
            return false;
        }
    }catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //System.ArgumentException argEx = new System.ArgumentException("Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password");
        //throw argEx;
        msg = "Wrong Email and/or Password!";
        return false;
    }
}
```